# In Windows 10, how shall I run a python script created and runnable in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, cmd, cygwin, windows-10

In Windows 10, I added the pathname of the parent directory of a python script `toc.py` to environment variable PATH. Then I tried to run it in two ways, but both failed:

In cmd

```
>toc.py -i toc -s syntax -p pn
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe "C:\Users\Tim\Downloads\self\bookmark\mine\toc2others.py"  -i toc -s syntax -p pn'
```

In Cygwin

```
$ toc.py  -i toc -p pn -s syntax
C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Users/Tim/Downloads/self/bookmark/mine/toc2others.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The python script `toc.py` was created to run with Python 2.7 under Ubuntu, and it looks like

```
#! /usr/bin/env python                                                                                              
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import pdb                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
from optparse import OptionParser        
...
```

What shall i do in order to run the python script in cmd ?

What shall i do in order to run the python script in  Cygwin?

Thanks.

---

Update:

i remove the shebang from the python script, and now

```
>toc.py -i toc -s syntax -p pn
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Downloads\self\bookmark\mine\toc.py", line 37
    print " "*level, root.value
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Is this error because of using Python 3 interpreter and Python 2.7 script?

Comment: The shebang is confusing as it doesn't hold across windows and cygwin. Remove the shebang and try running it with ```python toc.py -i toc -s syntax -p pn``` from Windows command line and/or Cygwin. This will allow windows or cygwin to use the correct version of Python to run the script.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Shall i also remove `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*   ` besides removing the shebang? (2) there is some new error, see my update.

Comment: @Tim If your Python script does not contain any non ASCII character with a code value greater 127 decimal, then yes, remove also the coding comment as not needed at all.

Comment: @Tim, yes, there are differences between Python 2 and 3. Python 2.7 for Windows can be downloaded from python.org.

Comment: This warning is because print is a function in Python 3. Actually parentheses work with print in Python 2.7 also. Put your print statements inside parentheses like ```print('BLAH')``` and that will solve that issue

Comment: In cygwin you should use the python provided by cygwin, not the windows one. Otherwise you risk always issue with different path format.